# Express & Backbone Integration

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

Ok, I am new to web dev and here's a stupid question. I have been through a few tutorials for node, express and backbone individually, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how they are integrated. Particularly, consider this use case:

Person X opens the browser, types in a URL and hits enter->Express responds to the request and sends some data back to the browser.

My question is, where does backbone come into the picture here ? I know it's a mvc framework to organize your JS code. But, I can't find a place in this use-case where the server/browser interacts with backbone. Only thing I can think of is that the backbone saving the route and serving the page the next time. But what about the first time ? It would be best if someone could explain to me how the request gets routed from client browser to express/backbone to browser again.

Also, am I correct in assuming response.send() or response.json() will send the result to backbone when model.fetch() is called ? I mean, is there no additional code required ? Being new to web dev, I'm quite not used to the idea of the framework 'taking care' of everything once you send the response back.

**EDIT** : Here's what I have understood so far. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong. When I access websites like gmail, the server first sends a big html file including backbone.js code in it. The backbone.js code listens for events like clicking on links in the html file and handles them if the links are defined in it routes(routes are always relative to current route, accessing a completely different route sends request to the server). So, if I click compose, my url remains the same because backbone handles the request. However, if I click Maps/News services in the bar above, the server handles the request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special integration between backbone and node.js.

If you use the standard backbone sync method then all you need to do is:

1. Use the static middleware in express to serve up your static html/js/... files.
2. Define RESTfule routes in express that conform to what backbone is expecting.

Backbone does indeed make an http call when you do model.fetch. You could look in Chome network tab to see where it's sending the request to and then implement that route in express.